# Python select option from Dropdown using Selenium Webdriver find_element_by_name instead of find_element_by_id

Tags: python, python-2.7, drop-down-menu

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
sizeselect = driver.find_element_by_name("skuAndSize")
Select(sizeselect).select_by_visible_text("13")
```

using find_element_by_id on other dropdowns works fine but name won't.

Comment: Without access to the website you're running this on, or HTML that we can test with ourselves, it's difficult to know what you're talking about/reproduce this.